# XHR not loading a XML local file

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I'm trying to load a XML file to a HTML document as seen [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery)

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Lemon_Bars.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
  });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("ing").each(function () {
    $("div[data-role='content']").append("<p>" + $(this).find("qty").text() + "</p>");
    $("div[data-role='content']").append("<p>" + $(this).find("unit").text() + "</p>");
    $("div[data-role='content']").append("<p>" + $(this).find("item").text() + "</p>");
  });
}
```

here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<recipeml version="0.5">
  <recipe>
    <head>
      <title>#1 Lemon Bars</title>
      <categories>
        <cat>Desserts</cat></categories>
      <yield>1</yield></head>
    <ingredients>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1 1/2</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>All-purpose flour</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>2/3</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Powdered sugar</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1 1/2</qty>
          <unit/></amt>
        <item>Sticks butter; softened</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>3</qty>
          <unit/></amt>
        <item>Eggs; lightly beaten</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1 1/2</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Granulated sugar</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>3</qty>
          <unit>tablespoons</unit></amt>
        <item>Flour</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty>1/4</qty>
          <unit>cups</unit></amt>
        <item>Lemon juice</item></ing>
      <ing>
        <amt>
          <qty/>
          <unit/></amt>
        <item>Additional powdered sugar</item></ing></ingredients>
    <directions>
      <step>  In bowl combine flour, sugar and butter.  Pat into 9X13 pan.  Bake for 20
  minutes in a 350F oven.  While it is baking, whisk together eggs, 3 TB
  flour, sugar and lemon juice.  Pour over crust while crust is still hot.
  Bake for an additional 20-25 minutes, or until top is golden brown. Cool on
  a wire rack and dust with additional powdered sugar.

  Posted to Bakery-Shoppe Digest V1 #206 by novmom@juno.com (Angela
  Gilliland) on Aug 29, 1997

</step></directions></recipe></recipeml>
```

and I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/.../Lemon_Bars.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I know I cannot load something from another domain, but why can't I access a document in the same folder? I know I can use JSONP, but is there any way to make this work or is it really deprecated by now (posts and tutorials are 4-6 y old).

If it truly doesn't work any more, what is the right way to do it with JSONP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

> **Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

I didn't knew what that exactly meant, but my assumption was, I should load the file via http, so I started XAMPP and loaded the file and it worked.